# How do you add a testing stage to a CodePipeline in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm having trouble finding the right reference because when I search, most of what I want is how to test constructs themselves. What I'm searching for is how to run my application tests, not the infrastructure/construct tests. Is that a testing stage that I should add?

The tests that I'm referring to are the ones normally run by running `npm test` (or `rake test` in the Ruby/Rails world, or `./manage.py test` in the Django world). Whether you call them integration or unit tests is debatable. They don't necessarily run a whole web server, but they do use the database. In my case these tests might use DynamoDB, SQS, and other services. The functions being tested would be a mixed of Lambda functions and their internal units. I wouldn't expect to run them in a Lambda environment. I would expect to run this tests locally on my machine constantly as I develop. These would be the tests that are run on a pull requests from GitHub as one of the things that block or allow the pull request to be merged. This is the standard Heroku CI/CD model in case you are familiar with that.

For reference, my current pipeline stack looks like this (it started from https://cdkworkshop.com/ and I'm evolving it, Example4Be is my application):

```js
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib"
import * as secretsmanager from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-secretsmanager"
import {Construct} from "constructs"
import {Example4BeDeployStage} from "./example4-be-deploy-stage"
import {CodeBuildStep, CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource} from "aws-cdk-lib/pipelines"

export class PipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        const githubSecretId = "github-flexpointtech-token"
        const secret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, githubSecretId)

        // The basic pipeline declaration. This sets the initial structure
        // of our pipeline
        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "Example4BePipeline", {
            synth: new CodeBuildStep("Synth", {
                    input: CodePipelineSource.gitHub("flexpointtech/example4-be", "main", {
                        authentication: cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager(githubSecretId)
                    }),
                    installCommands: [
                        "npm install -g aws-cdk"
                    ],
                    commands: [
                        "npm ci",
                        "npm run build",
                        "npx cdk synth"
                    ]
                }
            )
        })

        pipeline.node.addDependency(secret)

        const deploy = new Example4BeDeployStage(this, "Deploy")
        const deployStage = pipeline.addStage(deploy)

        deployStage.addPost(
            new CodeBuildStep("VerifyViewerEndpoint", {
                envFromCfnOutputs: {
                    ENDPOINT_URL: deploy.hcViewerUrl
                },
                commands: [
                    "curl -Ssf $ENDPOINT_URL"
                ]
            }),

            new CodeBuildStep("VerifyAPIGatewayEndpoint", {
                envFromCfnOutputs: {
                    ENDPOINT_URL: deploy.hcEndpoint
                },
                commands: [
                    "curl -Ssf $ENDPOINT_URL",
                    "curl -Ssf $ENDPOINT_URL/hello",
                    "curl -Ssf $ENDPOINT_URL/test"
                ]
            })
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Seems like you have it figured out with the tests - for unit tests to be run before deployment, you'd just use `addPre` instead of `addPost` to run the actions at the beginning of the stage. Regarding integration tests, you can't do those without deploying.

Comment: @gshpychka no, I didn't know that's how you are supposed to run tests in CodePipeline. That feels a bit primitive, but if that's the way, ok then :)

Comment: Your current code in the question runs tests in the pipeline with `curl` after deploying.

Comment: @gshpychka that just verifies that was deployed is working. I meant running test, as in `npm test`, or `jest`.

Comment: Yup, you can run them as an action with `addPre` or, if you're testing the CDK code itself, right in the synth action.

Comment: @gshpychka: but how would that work regarding things like: code coverage, static analysis, feeding back to github the result of the tests to approve/reject the commits? Just a few things I've done in the past in my projects. It doesn't sound like addPre has the sophistication to be the testing staging of a project.

Comment: It'd work the same as with any CI system, since CodeBuild allows you to run arbitrary cli commands. You can do all of those with a CodeBuildAction. The action will fail (and stop the deployment) if any of your commands exit with a non-zero return code. Let's move this to chat if you'd like to discuss further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240605/discussion-between-pupeno-and-gshpychka).

Answer (score 1):

I was following the aws documentation about it when dealing with the same problem and you can build a testing stack to run as a step. [You can find the documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html#cdk_pipeline_validation)

```js
import aws_cdk as cdk
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk.pipelines import CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ShellStep
from my_pipeline.my_pipeline_app_stage import MyPipelineAppStage

class MyPipelineStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        pipeline =  CodePipeline(self, "Pipeline", 
                        pipeline_name="MyPipeline",
                        synth=ShellStep("Synth", 
                            input=CodePipelineSource.git_hub("OWNER/REPO", "main"),
                            commands=["npm install -g aws-cdk",
                                "python -m pip install -r requirements.txt",
                                "cdk synth"]))

        pipeline.add_stage(MyPipelineAppStage(self, "test",
            env=cdk.Environment(account="111111111111", region="eu-west-1")))
```

You are running a step build separately

```js
import aws_cdk as cdk
from constructs import Construct
from my_pipeline.my_pipeline_lambda_stack import MyLambdaStack

class MyPipelineAppStage(cdk.Stage):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        lambdaStack = MyLambdaStack(self, "LambdaStack")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some CDK testing strategies. Not one-size-fits-all.

##### Unit Tests

Your unit tests ideally passed before you committed the PR to `main` in github (perhaps as a [github action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions)). No reason why you can't re-run them as a `npm run test` command in your pipeline.

##### Integration Tests

In many cases it makes sense to add a test deploy stage in a dedicated test account, following AWS's [multi-account best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-organization). One possible flow is:

```
[Build] -> [Test Deploy Stage] -> [Prod Deploy Stage] -> [Destroy Test Deploy Stage]
```

The `Test Deploy` stage is identical to `Prod Deploy` except for the account. You can [add test steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html#cdk_pipeline_validation) (e.g. verify API returns the expected value) after the test deploy stage. The pipeline tears down the test environment at the end of its execution.

You can add arbitrary testing code [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.Step.html) to arbitrary Pipeline [stages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipeline.html#addwbrstagestage-options) to support your preferred testing idioms cloud-side.  For more advanced use cases, you can seed data and perform arbitrary API calls with [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources).

##### AWS Amplify Frontend CI/CD

AWS Amplify has Heroku-/Netlify-like CI/CD features for front-end apps, including [testable web previews
for github PRs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/pr-previews.html).
CDK has [support for Amplify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-amplify-alpha-readme.html).(important: you want a Amplify "frontend" App, ignore the "backend")

##### Blue-Green Deployments

For lambda-based apps, the CDK has built-in blue-green deployments with [codedeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codedeploy.LambdaDeploymentGroup.html). AWS will gradually feed traffic to your updated lambda version, rolling back if it encounters errors.

Comment: You said "No reason why you can't re-run them as a npm run test command in your pipeline.". Yes, my question is what's the idiomatic way of doing this in CodePipeline. I would imagine later on I want to track code coverage, do static analysis, some other reports. I don't want to take the wrong path at this moment.

Comment: Also the github actions bring up another point which is feeding back the results to github. I'm not yet familiar with github actions, but at some point my tests will involve more than just code (like databases and other resources). Not sure how that interacts with GitHub actions.

Comment: Your edits added specific requirements.  That's helpful. "Testing" means something different to eveyone.  _Not one size fits all_, as my answer opens.  I expanded the answer somewhat to address your Heroku comment and provided links on CodePipeline steps/stages for running arbitrary pipeline testing code.

Comment: I think the question is still not good enough since it has a few assumptions that are in my head and not in the question. I'm going to work on it and update it.

Comment: "Your unit tests ideally passed before you committed the PR to main in github"  Surely it would be useful to have unit tests run as part of the pipeline. This is the crux of the question that OP is asking and your answer just sweeps it under the rug.