# How to create AWS resources to run a CDK application locally using SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-sam

I have an application called Example4Be, I have a stack that creates the AWS non-Lambda resources (just DynamoDB in this case, but could be SQS, SNS, etc):

```js
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib"
import {Construct} from "constructs"
import * as dynamodb from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb"

export class Example4BeResourcesStack extends cdk.Stack {
    public readonly table: dynamodb.Table

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StageProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        this.table = new dynamodb.Table(this, "Hits", {
            partitionKey: {
                name: "path",
                type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And then there's a stack that uses it:

```js
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib"
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda"
import * as apigw from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway"
import {Construct} from "constructs"
import {Example4BeResourcesStack} from "./example4-be-resources-stack";

export class Example4BeStack extends cdk.Stack {
    public readonly hcEndpoint: cdk.CfnOutput

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StageProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        const resources = new Example4BeResourcesStack(scope, `${id}Resources`)

        const hello = new lambda.Function(this, "HelloHandler", {
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("lambda"),
            handler: "hello.handler",
            environment: {
                HITS_TABLE_NAME: resources.table.tableName
            }
        })

        resources.table.grantReadWriteData(hello)

        // defines an API Gateway REST API resource backed by our "hello" function.
        const gateway = new apigw.LambdaRestApi(this, "Endpoint", {
            handler: hello
        })

        this.hcEndpoint = new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "GatewayUrl", {
            value: gateway.url
        })
    }
}
```

I have a file, `app.ts` that instantiates the stack:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib"
import {Example4BeStack} from "../lib/example4-be-stack";

const app = new cdk.App()
new Example4BeStack(app, "Example4BePipeline")
```

and the way I run it is by running:

```
cdk synth --no-staging > template.yaml
sam local start-api
```

but this doesn't seem to create the DynamoDB table. I guess there's a `cdk deploy` that I'm missing? How should this be done?

I'm happy to add more of the application if you want, there's CodePipeline involved in the actual deployment.

Comment: hi, would this be for a local test perhaps? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-cdk-testing.html

Comment: @jspcal: I am calling `sam local start-api`, which is one of the methods described on that document you linked to, but that document doesn't say anything about the resources needed by the Lambda functions being tested locally, which is what I'm asking about. I guess if you have an app doesn't does write, read, send, or receive anything, something purely compute, that would work, but I will have DynamoDB, Cognito, SQS, SNS.

Comment: Do you want to mock DynamoDB, Cognito, SQS and SNS locally, or do you want the lambda function to make API calls to the actual cloud resources when you are testing the application using `sam local`?

Comment: I want to use the real services when developing, so it'll have to make calls to AWS.

Answer (score 5):

[SAM-CDK integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-cdk-testing.html) runs emulated lambdas locally, calling cloud-deployed resources as required.

##### (1) Deploy your stacks using `cdk deploy`

Our local-lambdas will interact with deployed-resource<sup>1</sup> dependencies (tables, queues, etc).  It's an AWS best practice to use a [separate account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html) for testing.<sup>2</sup>

##### (2) Tell SAM about the lambdas' cloud-side [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke.html#serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke-environment-file).

```json
// locals.json is used by SAM to resolve lambda env vars
{
  // the lambda resource id from sam-template.yaml 
  "HandlerFunctionEDBA20C2": { 
    // our lambda has an environment variable named TABLE_NAME
    // this is deployed-resource in cloud - tip: define a CfnOutput in your stack.  cdk deploy will emit the values to the terminal
    "TABLE_NAME": "CdkTsPlayLocalTestingStack-SuperTable2CB94566-1VPR5PAXO0GM5" 
  },
  "AnotherLambdaCD21C99": {
    "QUEUE_ARN": "<queue-arn>"
  }
}
```

or you can have a single set of variables apply to all functions:

```json
{
  "Parameters": {
    "TABLE_NAME": "CdkTsPlayLocalTestingStack-SuperTable2CB94566-1VPR5PAXO0GM5" 
  }
}
```

##### (3) Now you can iterate locally

Make a change to your lambdas locally, then let the SAM cli do its thing<sup>3</sup>:

```sh
# synth the app template, output a sam format template
npx cdk synth '*' -a 'ts-node ./bin/app.ts' --profile <testing-profile> --no-staging > cdk.out/sam-template.yaml

# call a local function
sam local invoke HandlerFunctionEDBA20C2 \
--template cdk.out/sam-template.yaml \
--profile <testing-profile> \
--event lib/stacks/testing/LocalTestingStack/test-events/create.json \
--env-vars lib/stacks/testing/LocalTestingStack/locals.json
```

##### (4) Or integrate with automated tests

`start-lambda` starts emulator, automated tests run against the local endpoint.  [Docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-automated-tests.html).

#### What is happening where?

SAM currently has 3 local test commands:

| SAM command | lambda | apigw | other (dynamo, etc) | what for |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [sam local invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-invoke.html) | local |  | cloud | test a local lambda |
| [sam local start-lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html) | local |  | cloud | watch mode - call a lambda with SDK or CLI |
| [sam local start-api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html) | local | local | cloud | watch mode - test local lambda via a local endpoint |

Note that lambdas are the center of all this goodness.  We can mock event inputs into local-lambdas.  We can emulate an api/sdk endpoint.  We can interact with deployed-resources referenced by lambda SDK calls.  But other setups are not currently covered.  For instance, we can't test a lambda DynamoDB streams handler.  Let's hope the local functionality will grow over time.

---

(1) I use the term "local-lambda" to mean a local version of the lambda, which `sam local` will run in a container. "deployed-resources" refers to our lambda's cloud-deployed integrations (e.g. DynamoDB tables, queues, etc.).

(2) At this point, testing does not touch your pipeline stack. Once you are done with local testing, push your changes to github, which will kick off the pipeline deploy to (`staging` and) `prod` accounts. You can have [additional testing steps run as part of the pipeline stages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70542355/1103511).

(3) The preview `sam-beta-cdk` CLI [makes it somewhat easier to integrate CDK with SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-aws-sam-and-aws-cdk/) than the vanilla CLI `sam`.  For instance, it seems to create the sam `.yaml` for us.  But the two tools appear to have same underlying functionality.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detail answer. I'll get on it as soon as I can.

Comment: Where are the values in `locals.json` coming from? Is this file constructed manually?

Comment: Yes, [manually](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke.html#serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke-environment-file).  The `env` file values are the deployed-resource ids (see the code comments).  The AWS blog post linked in footnote #3 also has an example.

Comment: Isn't maintaining that file quite cumbersome? I'm trying to find a nice path of development and everything seems to have massive boulders in the middle.

Comment: Regarding sam-beta-cdk. I can't find it. I assumed it was already merged into sam/cdk, since that article is almost a year old?

Comment: I don't know the status of `sam-beta-cdk`, @pupeno.  I never used it, for the reason given in footnote #3.

Answer (score 2):

Since @fedonev has already answered the question, I will focus on a potential implementation using CodePipeline (specifically CDK Pipelines in Python), since I had been already working on it. I restricted myself to not using anything which is experimental or preview.

Code for the example: https://github.com/KMK-Git/aws-cdk-sam-testing-demo

## The Flow

[image]

## Stages

### Source

[image]

```python
source = pipelines.CodePipelineSource.connection(
    "KMK-Git/aws-cdk-sam-testing-demo",
    "main",
    connection_arn=ssm.StringParameter.value_for_string_parameter(
        self,
        "codestar_connection_arn",
    ),
)
```

The source code repository is configured using CodeStar connections. The connection was done manually beforehand, and I am getting the ARN from SSM parameter store.

### Build, SelfMutate and UploadAssets

[image]
[image]
[image]

```python
cdk_codepipeline = pipelines.CodePipeline(
    self,
    "Pipeline",
    synth=pipelines.ShellStep(
        "Synth",
        input=source,
        install_commands=[
            "pip install -r requirements.txt",
            "npm install -g aws-cdk",
        ],
        commands=[
            "cdk synth",
        ],
    ),
)
```

- The Synth stage is used to synthesize the CDK code into CloudFormation templates.
- The SelfMutate stage is a CDK feature to update the pipeline inside the pipeline itself. This allows you to make changes to your pipeline even after the initial deployment.
- The Assets stage uploads all cdk assets to their destinations, using the cdk-assets command. Since I have separated my stacks into two separate stages, each one gets its own assets upload step.

In case you are not using CDK Pipelines, here is the build spec for all stages:

For Synth:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "install": {
      "commands": [
        "pip install -r requirements.txt",
        "npm install -g aws-cdk"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "cdk synth"
      ]
    }
  },
  "artifacts": {
    "base-directory": "cdk.out",
    "files": "**/*"
  }
}
```

For SelfMutate:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "install": {
      "commands": [
        "npm install -g aws-cdk"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "cdk -a . deploy PipelineStack --require-approval=never --verbose"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For Assets:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "install": {
      "commands": [
        "npm install -g cdk-assets"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "cdk-assets --path \"assembly-LambdaStage/LambdaStageLambdasStackABCD123.assets.json\" --verbose publish \"longrandomstring:current_account-current_region\""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Unit Testing

```python
testing = pipelines.CodeBuildStep(
    "UnitTesting",
    input=source,
    install_commands=[
        "pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements-dev.txt",
    ],
    commands=[
        "pytest --cov",
    ],
    env={
        "QUEUE_URL": "SampleQueue",
        "TABLE_NAME": "SampleTest",
    },
    build_environment=codebuild.BuildEnvironment(
        build_image=codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0,
        privileged=True,
        compute_type=codebuild.ComputeType.SMALL,
    ),
)
```

This is a simple step, which runs any unit tests in your code.

In case you are not using CDK Pipelines, here is the build spec:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "install": {
      "commands": [
        "pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements-dev.txt"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "pytest --cov"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Deploy Supporting resources

[image]

```python
cdk_codepipeline.add_stage(
    supporting_resources_stage,
    pre=[
        testing,
        pipelines.ConfirmPermissionsBroadening(
            "CheckSupporting", stage=supporting_resources_stage
        ),
    ],
)
```

This would deploy the supporting resources, which are required for your `sam local` tests to run properly. The permissions broadening step stops the pipeline and forces manual approval in case of any broadening of IAM permissions. You can add unit testing in its own separate stage as well.

In case you are not using CDK Pipelines, here is the build spec:

```json
{
  "version": 0.2,
  "phases": {
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "npm install -g aws-cdk",
        "export PIPELINE_NAME=\"$(node -pe '`${process.env.CODEBUILD_INITIATOR}`.split(\"/\")[1]')\"",
        "payload=\"$(node -pe 'JSON.stringify({ \"PipelineName\": process.env.PIPELINE_NAME, \"StageName\": process.env.STAGE_NAME, \"ActionName\": process.env.ACTION_NAME })' )\"",
        "ARN=$CODEBUILD_BUILD_ARN",
        "REGION=\"$(node -pe '`${process.env.ARN}`.split(\":\")[3]')\"",
        "ACCOUNT_ID=\"$(node -pe '`${process.env.ARN}`.split(\":\")[4]')\"",
        "PROJECT_NAME=\"$(node -pe '`${process.env.ARN}`.split(\":\")[5].split(\"/\")[1]')\"",
        "PROJECT_ID=\"$(node -pe '`${process.env.ARN}`.split(\":\")[6]')\"",
        "export LINK=\"https://$REGION.console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codebuild/$ACCOUNT_ID/projects/$PROJECT_NAME/build/$PROJECT_NAME:$PROJECT_ID/?region=$REGION\"",
        "export PIPELINE_LINK=\"https://$REGION.console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codepipeline/pipelines/$PIPELINE_NAME/view?region=$REGION\"",
        "if cdk diff -a . --security-only --fail $STAGE_PATH/\\*; then aws lambda invoke --function-name PipelineStack-PipelinePipelinesSecurityCheckCDKalpha-numeric --invocation-type Event --payload \"$payload\" lambda.out; export MESSAGE=\"No security-impacting changes detected.\"; else [ -z \"${NOTIFICATION_ARN}\" ] || aws sns publish --topic-arn $NOTIFICATION_ARN --subject \"$NOTIFICATION_SUBJECT\" --message \"An upcoming change would broaden security changes in $PIPELINE_NAME.\nReview and approve the changes in CodePipeline to proceed with the deployment.\n\nReview the changes in CodeBuild:\n\n$LINK\n\nApprove the changes in CodePipeline (stage $STAGE_NAME, action $ACTION_NAME):\n\n$PIPELINE_LINK\"; export MESSAGE=\"Deployment would make security-impacting changes. Click the link below to inspect them, then click Approve if all changes are expected.\"; fi"
      ]
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "exported-variables": [
      "LINK",
      "MESSAGE"
    ]
  }
}
```

### sam local testing

```python
sam_cli_test_step = pipelines.CodeBuildStep(
    "SAMTesting",
    input=source,
    env_from_cfn_outputs={
        "QUEUE_URL": supporting_resources_stage.stack.queue_url,
        "TABLE_NAME": supporting_resources_stage.stack.table_name,
    },
    install_commands=[
        "pip install -r requirements.txt",
        "npm install -g aws-cdk",
        "mkdir testoutput",
    ],
    commands=[
        'cdk synth -a "python synth_lambdas_stack.py" -o sam.out',
        'echo "{\\""SqsLambdaFunction\\"": {\\""QUEUE_URL\\"": \\""$QUEUE_URL\\""},'
        + '\\""DynamodbLambdaFunction\\"": {\\""TABLE_NAME\\"": \\""$TABLE_NAME\\"" }}"'
        + " > locals.json",
        'sam local invoke -t "sam.out/LambdasStack.template.json" --env-vars locals.json'
        + ' --no-event "DynamodbLambdaFunction"',
        'sam local invoke -t "sam.out/LambdasStack.template.json" --env-vars locals.json'
        + ' --no-event "SqsLambdaFunction"',
        "nohup sam local start-api -t sam.out/LambdasStack.template.json"
        + " --env-vars locals.json > testoutput/testing.log & ",
        "",
        "sleep 30",
        "curl --fail http://127.0.0.1:3000/sqs",
        "curl --fail http://127.0.0.1:3000/dynamodb",
    ],
    build_environment=codebuild.BuildEnvironment(
        build_image=codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0,
        privileged=True,
        compute_type=codebuild.ComputeType.SMALL,
    ),
    primary_output_directory="testoutput/",
    role_policy_statements=[
        iam.PolicyStatement(
            actions=[
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
                "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
            ],
            resources=["*"],
        ),
        iam.PolicyStatement(
            actions=[
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            ],
            resources=["*"],
        ),
    ],
)
```

- In your supporting resources stack, you will need to define any parameters like resource names and ARNs which your Lambda code needs as stack outputs. I have provided these values to my Lambda function using environment variables.
- In my stack code, I have specified the logical ids of the CloudFormation Lambda function resource instead of relying on CDK's auto generated value.

```python
sqs_lambda_base: _lambda.CfnFunction = sqs_lambda.node.default_child
sqs_lambda_base.override_logical_id("SqsLambdaFunction")
```

- I have created a separate app file which only synthesizes my Lambda stack, instead of the full Pipeline stack. In theory you should be able to use the synth output of the full stack, but this is simpler to configure.
- I have added permissions needed by my Lambdas to interact with the resources created by my supporting resources stack.
- `sam-beta-cdk` can be used to simplify some of this workflow, but I did not use it here since it is still in preview.

In case you are not using CDK Pipelines, here is the build spec:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "install": {
      "commands": [
        "pip install -r requirements.txt",
        "npm install -g aws-cdk",
        "curl --version",
        "mkdir testoutput"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "cdk synth -a \"python synth_lambdas_stack.py\" -o sam.out",
        "echo \"{\\\"\"SqsLambdaFunction\\\"\": {\\\"\"QUEUE_URL\\\"\": \\\"\"$QUEUE_URL\\\"\"},\\\"\"DynamodbLambdaFunction\\\"\": {\\\"\"TABLE_NAME\\\"\": \\\"\"$TABLE_NAME\\\"\" }}\" > locals.json",
        "sam local invoke -t \"sam.out/LambdasStack.template.json\" --env-vars locals.json --no-event \"DynamodbLambdaFunction\"",
        "sam local invoke -t \"sam.out/LambdasStack.template.json\" --env-vars locals.json --no-event \"SqsLambdaFunction\"",
        "nohup sam local start-api -t sam.out/LambdasStack.template.json --env-vars locals.json > testoutput/testing.log & ",
        "",
        "sleep 30",
        "curl --fail http://127.0.0.1:3000/sqs",
        "curl --fail http://127.0.0.1:3000/dynamodb"
      ]
    }
  },
  "artifacts": {
    "base-directory": "testoutput/",
    "files": "**/*"
  }
}
```

### Deploy Lambda functions

[image]

```python
cdk_codepipeline.add_stage(
    lambdas_stage,
    pre=[
        sam_cli_test_step,
        pipelines.ConfirmPermissionsBroadening(
            "CheckLambda", stage=lambdas_stage
        ),
    ],
)
```

This is similar to the deploy supporting resources stage. You can add sam local testing in its own separate stage as well.

## Notes:

- DynamoDB specifically has support for [local testing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) if you don't want to deploy it first.
- While my pipeline only deploys one set of resources, you can create different stages deploying to different environments/accounts.
- The sam local testing step defined here is very simple. You can use features like API testing tools to run a whole suite of test cases. [Here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codebuild-polyglot-application/blob/master/buildspec.yml) is an official AWS sample that uses selenium to test a web server, with the APIs running on sam local.

## Limitations

- API Gateway authorizers are [not supported](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/137) for `sam local` testing, so you won't be able to test Cognito authorizers if you are planning to use them.

Comment: I decided to try LocalStack as an alternative, since this seems to be getting out of hand in complexity. I awarded the existing bounty to the previous question, and in 24hs I'll award you the same amount for such an amazing detailed respond and code example. Thank you so much. I may find myself coming back to this, but since I can't pick a winning _correct_ answer, I wanted at least to make sure the bounties were awarded fairly.

Comment: @pupeno Thank you, I wasn't expecting that! Also, out of curiosity, are you going to use localstack as part of your CI pipeline or only for local development?

Comment: I tried localstack but it couldn't even do `cdk bootstrap`, so I'm not sure that's *the* path.