# Run SQS on AWS SAM locally. Is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, sam

Good morning! does AWS SAM natively support sqs service? i am looking for a way to run sqs service locally?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Only in a limited sense and in no way "native".  You can use SAM to *locally* test Lambdas that make outbound SDK calls to *cloud-deployed* SQS queues.  You can invoke *local* Lambdas with mock [triggering events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-generate-event.html) to simulate invocation by queue messages.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70725727/1103511) to a related question, skipping point #1, which is specific to CDK applications.

Answer (score 0):

This PR may interest you. It provides only basic emulation of AWS SQS with lambda.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/pull/3643